# How to pass action name from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to razor and I need help to pass the action name from controller to view using ViewBag. Following is my code:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id = 0)
    {
        ViewBag.MasterId = id;
        ViewBag.ActionName = "ApplicationProcess";
        return View();
    }
```

From the above action method I am passing action name of that is being used in view that is render in result of this function.

```
<body>
    <h2>Index</h2>
    <div style="width: 1100px;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 400px;">
            @{Html.RenderAction("MasterRecordProcess", "Process");}
        </div>
        <div style="float: right">
            @{Html.RenderAction("MasterRecordBasicInfo", "Process", new { id = ViewBag.MasterId });}
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;margin-top:50px;" class="task-div">
            @{Html.RenderAction(@ViewBag.ActionName, "Process", null);}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now in above view I want to use the **ViewBag.ActionName** passed from controller in **Html.RenderAction** but this is giving me error message.

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<OAC.Areas.Personal.Models.MasterModel>' has no applicable method named 'RenderAction' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.
```

Kindly help how can I render the action name passed from controller in viewBag object. Thank you.

Comment: Cast it to a string - `(string)ViewBag.ActionName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Stephen mentioned you must first cast the view bag content:

```
@{
    var actionName= (string)ViewBag.ActionName;
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
@{Html.RenderAction(actionName, "Process", null);}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error itself says that "***consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.***"

C# does not support calling an extension method (`Html.RenderAction()`) when any of the arguments is of a dynamic type. You have to either call the extension method statically or cast the argument to a non-dynamic type.

In this case you can the `ViewBag` to a `String` and use